# How to handle java.lang.NullPointerException in this code

Tags: java, exception

This is my Code
and it throws `java.lang.NullPointerException`
I tried to handle it using other similar topics on this site but it wasn't useful.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.lang.Long;


public class Tamrin7 {

    public static  BigInteger ZERO;
    public static  BigInteger ONE;
    public static  BigInteger TEN;
    public static void main(String[] args){

        BigInteger a = ZERO ;
        BigInteger b = ZERO ;
        BigInteger increment = ONE ;
        int counter = 0 ;
        int thirteen = 13;
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(thirteen));
        while(counter != 10000){
            b = a.add(inverse(a))   ;
            if (b.remainder(bigInt) == ZERO)
                ++counter;
            a = a.add(increment);
        }//end of while

        String finall = b.toString();

        System.out.printf("the value of the 10000th number is %s :" , finall );


    }//end of main
    public static BigInteger inverse (BigInteger c){
        BigInteger inversedNum = ZERO ; 
        while (c != ZERO){
            inversedNum = inversedNum.multiply(TEN).add(c.remainder(TEN));
            c = c.divide(TEN);
        }//end of while
        return inversedNum ;
    }
}//end of class
```

Comment: Throws a `NullPointerException` *where*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems here.

```
public static  BigInteger ZERO;
public static  BigInteger ONE;
public static  BigInteger TEN;
```

These are never initialized with values, that's why you get the null pointer in the first place.
If you want this to work, you should create objects with or provide a reference to existing ones.

Like so:

```
public static final BigInteger ZERO = BigInteger.ZERO;
public static final BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.ONE;
public static final BigInteger TEN = BigInteger.TEN;
```

But you should just use BigInteger.ZERO instead of re-declaring them in your code.

Also, dont do this:

```
 BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(thirteen));
```

BigInteger has a factory method, that can consume plain int, without having it to be casted to String.

Like so:

```
 BigInteger bigInt = BigInteger.valueOf(thirteen);
```

Comment: Or just `new BigInteger("13")`.  One can be too clever about these things.

Comment: Right, or BigInteger.valueOf(13) ;) So we don't mess with people heads :) I prefer my numeric values to have numeric data types, not string representations of them :)

Comment: Weird, I was sure I had put that last comment under @BoristheSpider's answer.  I guess it works just as well here.

Answer (score 3):

Where do you initialise these:

```
public static  BigInteger ZERO;
public static  BigInteger ONE;
public static  BigInteger TEN;
```

I don't think you do:

```
public static  BigInteger ZERO = BigInteger.ZERO;
public static  BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.ONE;
public static  BigInteger TEN = BigInteger.TEN;
```

Or, if you're into `import static` then:

```
import static java.math.BigInteger.ZERO;
import static java.math.BigInteger.ONE;
import static java.math.BigInteger.TEN;
```

And delete your declarations.

Also this:

```
new BigInteger(String.valueOf(thirteen));
```

Makes a cry a little:

```
BigInteger.valueOf(thirteen);
```

Will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There:

```
public static  BigInteger ZERO;
public static  BigInteger ONE;
public static  BigInteger TEN;
```

look like they need *initialising*. e.g.

```
public static  BigInteger ZERO = BigInteger.ZERO;
```

otherwise they're simply *declared* object references and consequently null.

Answer (score -1):

You need to initialize ZERO, ONE and TEN.

I think you wanted to do something like this:

```
public static final BigInteger ZERO = BigInteger.ZERO;
public static final BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.ONE;
public static final BigInteger TEN = BigInteger.TEN;
```

You don't need to declare them as constants though, you can just them.